# I cannot connect to 1 specific network

Tags: networking, wireless, internet

If I try to connect to a network it asks for a encryption key. I cannot enter the encryption key because there is non. It is a username and password network. All the other networks work properly (and are not username and password). It is very strange and I have Ubuntu 16.04.5 LXT. Thanks already.

Comment: Ethernet? Are you the owner of the network? How are you "trying to connect"?

Comment: "I cannot enter the encryption key because there is non. It is a username and password network."  The latter does not exclude the former. If that system asks for an ssh key you will need to check that system on how it was set up. This is likely not a problem on your side.